# Apply automatically apply cell-spacing or padding based on "margin" given for IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

O have a polyfill for IE7 that transforms `display:table` into actual tables and I'm using `IE7.js` (`IE9.js` file).
Both are working wonderfully and both are doing a great job allowing us devs to think less on IE7.

This is what I have (join of main sheet and IE7 specific sheet):

```
/*IE7*/
.sideBySide{
    display:table;
}
.sideBySide > *{
    display:table-cell;
}
/*MAIN*/
.A{
    margin-left: 20px;
}



<li>
    <div class="sideBySide">
        <img class="img" src="img">
        <div class="sideBySide">
            <div class="A">Info A</div>
            <div class="A">Info B</div>
        </div>
        <div>OK</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

This is what the polyfills generate:

```
<style>
    ........ .A{
        /* CSS that overrides and invalidates what was set for A */
    }
    .newClassA{
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .newClassA > /*etc*/{
        /* All properties relative to class A */
    }

</style>

<li>
    <div class="sideBySide">
        <img class="img" src="img">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="newClassA">Info A</td>
                    <td class="newClassA">Info B</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>OK</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

The `<style>` tag is placed as the last one in the `<head>`.

In order to deal with this, I made this:

```
.sideBySide > * > * > td{
    padding-left: expression(this.currentStyle['marginLeft']);
}
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work. Although the CSS clearly gives that it should have a marginLeft of `20px`, instead, it is returning `auto`... So `padding-left` becomes `auto`.

Is there a way to seamlessly polyfill this? No one here minds if it requires a substantial amount of computation as long as the browser doesn't hang because of it.

One main thing I want this to follow that this is supposed to be reusable parts. If I set the CSS either in the stylesheet or inline for the other browsers, IE7 must follow it too.

**NOTE:** 
I can tell that those two are working exactly as specified here and it is not a bug on any of them. My issue is that working as specified doesn't help for this specific use-case.
No matter how much I want to ditch IE7... And even IE8, the contractor wants us to support it for some more years.

Comment: Should we support the lesser ie browsers? http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201412-201512 ---- https://www.dropbox.com/s/jroguns8ikl8hjc/browser-support-ie.png?dl=0

Comment: @CarolMcKay Read the last paragraph please.

Comment: I appologise for not reading that bit @brunoais and you have my condolences I shall try and turn my brain on again now.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

css

```
.sideBySide table {
  border-collapse:separate;
}
```

html

```
<div class="sideBySide">
    <img class="img" src="img">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="newClassA">Info A</td>
                    <td class="newClassA">Info B</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <div>OK</div>
</div>
```

Comment: IE7 doesn't know what `border-collapse:separate;` is and, even with the polyfill, it doesn't gain the possibility for having a margin because it is a table

Comment: would you get away with substituting margin with padding space just for ie7? Explain that some miracles can't be performed?

Comment: I would if I can make it happen automatically